# Count column multiple times with different where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores an `admin_id` and `comment` and I am trying to query it to get a count of the different comments associated with each admin.

I am trying to do this like so:

```
select admin_id, 
        count(comment like 'Approved the claim for%') as Approved,
        count(comment like 'Rejected the claim for%') as Rejected,
        count(comment like 'Temporarily rejected (24 hour hold) the claim for%') as TempReject, 
        count(comment like 'Permanently rejected the claim for%') as PermReject
from admin_comments
group by admin_id
```

However this is producing results where the columns `Approved`, `Rejected`, `TempReject` and `PermReject` are all the same, as well as a row at the top that seems to SUM them all together where the `admin_id` is `NULL`:

[image]

What do I need to change in my query to get accurate figures for each type of comment grouped by `admin_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :** USE CASE Expression for this purpose

```
select admin_id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN comment like 'Approved the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Approved,
    SUM(CASE WHEN comment like 'Rejected the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Rejected,
    SUM(CASE WHEN comment like 'Temporarily rejected (24 hour hold) the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TempReject, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN comment like 'Permanently rejected the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as PermReject
from admin_comments
group by admin_id
```

Comment: That produced a NULL result for every row and every column.

Comment: Try Updated Ans

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

COUNT Doesn't do Boolean expressions, so you cannot use LIKE inside COUNT. You have to use CASE/WHEN

```
select admin_id, 
        count( WHEN comment like 'Approved the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Approved,
        count(WHEN comment like 'Rejected the claim for%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ....
```

Note that it has to be NULL and not 0 because COUNT counts non null values. O is a non null value

Answer (score 1):

```
 select admin_id, 
        count(case when comment like 'Approved the claim for%' then 1 else null end) as Approved,
        count(case when comment like 'Rejected the claim for%' then 1 else null end) as Rejected,
        count(case when comment like 'Temporarily rejected (24 hour hold) the claim for%' then 1 else null end) as TempReject, 
        count(case when comment like 'Permanently rejected the claim for%' then 1 else null end ) as PermReject
    from admin_comments
 group by admin_id
```